# Can I Get JVM Flags From HPROF File?

Tags: java

I had an OutOfMemoryError and the heap was dumped.
Is it possible to read the JVM flags from this hprof file?

Specifically, I would like to find out what the `Xmx` was set at.
It might have been set explicitly or it might not.

I can't find anything obvious in Eclipse Memory Analyzer or VisualVM

Comment: have you tried to import you hprof file into MAT http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ ?

Comment: The last line in the question says that I have.

Answer (score 1):

find class sun.management.RuntimeImpl to get RuntimeImpl -> jvm -> vmArgs -> Arraylist
then get values:
    ...
    ref[2]->-Xmx24576m
    ref[3]->-XX:MetaspaceSize=128m
    ...